# How to denormalize the output in a Neural Network (MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, simulation, training-data, data-fitting

I'm a junior in neural networks and I have a NN that is trained to fit the input data with the target data and then simulate the NN on a new sample data to get a prediction output.

The problem is the output is normalized values that are between "zero" and "one" and I need to transform (denormalize) them to real values like "decimals".

Could you explain how to do this?

I've read that I have to use an activation function, but I didn't understand how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the training set was created and you normalize the output values, you probably used min-max normalization (or mean-std normalization):

```
z = (x - min) / (max - min)
```

Where z is the normalized output. To get the unnormalized value, you just have to store the min and max values used for normalization, then invert the equation:

```
x = (max - min) * z + min
```

For other kinds of normalization, the same procedure is done. Just remember that the normalization factors have to be obtained from the original training set.

Comment: % initialize NN: 
net = newff(minmax([input sample]),[3 10 10 10 1] ); 

% net parameters: 
net.trainFcn  =  'trainlm';
net.trainParam.lr = 0.1;
net.trainParam.epochs = 500;
net.trainParam.goal = 0.0;

% initialize training: 
[net, tr] = train(net,input,target);

Comment: please take a look at the above sample code, for this kind of normalization  in the initializing step of the NN (minmax), How can I make the opposite process?

Comment: @MohamedNedal If you are asking about a function call that reverts the process, there is probably none, as you need to save the min/max factors to undo the process. Implementing the math should be trivial.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot.